# Erro no Cabeçalho do PHP 5.6 tentei de tudo que conheço e não funciona

Tags: php

estou tendo erros com PHP, 5.6 Padrão, antigamente funcionava. agora está apresentando erros.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/maxiimpo/public_html/maxiimanager/revcal/index.php:1) in /home/maxiimpo/public_html/maxiimanager/revcal/index.php on line 2

se repete até...

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/maxiimpo/public_html/maxiimanager/revcal/index.php:1) in
>   /home/maxiimpo/public_html/maxiimanager/revcal/index.php on line 26

```
    <?PHP 
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header("Status: 404 Not Found");

include ('jobs.php');

        setcookie ('pg_adm_id','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_nome',''); 
        setcookie ('pg_adm_add_pad','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_edit_pad','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_del_pad','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_add_cli','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_edit_cli','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_del_cli','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_add_cer','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_edit_cer',''); 
        setcookie ('pg_adm_del_cer',''); 
        setcookie ('pg_adm_ver_his','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_pod_ass','');
        setcookie ('pg_adm_edi_adm','');
        setcookie ('pg_login_ativo','');
        setcookie ('pg_cli_id','');// cadastro do cookie em certificados

        //LIMPEZA DO LOGIN INVALIDO
        setcookie ('MAXI_pg_adm_user_teste','');
        setcookie ('MAXI_pg_adm_senha_teste','');

?>


<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='images/maxiimpor-ico.png'/>
<title>MAXIIMPOR - Manager</title>
</head>
<script type='text/javascript'>// <![CDATA[
var imageCount = 0;
var currentImage = 0;
var images = new Array();

images[0] = 'images/fundo/imagens1.jpg';
images[1] = 'images/fundo/imagens2.jpg';
images[2] = 'images/fundo/imagens3.jpg';
images[3] = 'images/fundo/imagens4.jpg';
images[4] = 'images/fundo/imagens5.jpg';
images[5] = 'images/fundo/imagens6.jpg';
images[6] = 'images/fundo/imagens7.jpg';
images[7] = 'images/fundo/imagens8.jpg';

var preLoadImages = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
   if (images[i] == '')
      break;

   preLoadImages[i] = new Image();
   preLoadImages[i].src = images[i];
   imageCount++;
}

function startSlideShow()
{
   if (document.body && imageCount > 0)
   {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+images[currentImage]+')';    
      document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = 'fixed';
      document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'repeat';
      document.body.style.backgroundPosition = 'left top';

      currentImage = currentImage + 1;
      if (currentImage > (imageCount-1))
      { 
         currentImage = 0;
      }
      setTimeout('startSlideShow()', 60000);
   }
}
// ]]></script>
<body>
<script>
startSlideShow();
</script>
<table width='50%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <td width='38' height='80' background='images/contorno/esquerdo-top.png'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center' valign='middle' background='images/contorno/centro-top.png'><table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='15'>
      <tr>
        <td align='center'><img src='images/Logo.png' alt=''  /></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td width='38' background='images/contorno/direito-top.png'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='38' background='images/contorno/esquerdo-meio.png'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><form id='login adm' name='login adm' method='post' action='loginteste.php'><table width='50%' border='0' align='center'>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' align='center'><strong>Acesso ao sistema</strong></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width='30%' align='right'><strong>User:</strong></td>
        <td width='70%' align='left'><input name='pg-adm-user' type='text' required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align='right'><strong>Senha:</strong></td>
        <td align='left'><input name='pg-adm-senha' type='password' required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='Logar' id='Logar' value='Logar' /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </form></td>
    <td width='38' background='images/contorno/direito-meio.png'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='38' height='70' background='images/contorno/esquerdo-inferior.png'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center' valign='middle' background='images/contorno/centro-inferior.png'><? echo $MAXI_VERSÃO;?></td>
    <td width='38' background='images/contorno/direito-inferior.png'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cuidado que qualquer espaço em branco, `echo`, `print`, etc já inicia o envio do corpo da resposta HTTP, não possibilitando mais definir os cabeçalhos. Os quatro espaços em branco antes de `<?PHP` do seu código é um exemplo, mas o problema pode estar também em `jobs.php`.

Comment: provavelmente o arquivo 'jobs.php' ja deve ter mandado codigo de saida para o navegador